# How to fetch hierarchical entries from database using python

Tags: python, django, recursion, mapping, cascadingdropdown

I have 3 interdependent dropdowns in a django project, Level1, Level2 and Level3. These levels may increase. The mapping of these dropdowns is available in below format:
Table Name is LevelMapping
[image]

From the above mapping, I want to create a mapping as follows:
Team | Level1 | Level2 | Level3
[image]

How to get the mapping using recursion in python django?

Comment: Just use django-mptt - https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/